# How to detect route change in Angular 1.5 component router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-component-router

I am using angular 1.5 component router in my application. Is there a way to detect route change in component router. I want to run some code on route change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sajeetharan s' answer is correct but its only for current scope.If you want it for every state change add it like this

```
run.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$location', '$cookieStore', '$http'];

   function run($rootScope, $location, $cookieStore, $http) {
     $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {

           console.log($location.path());

       });
   }
   app.run(run);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do with this piece of code,

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event) {
     //add your logic
});
```